# Javascript : Display "Today" from today's date or "Yesterday" from yesterday's date

Tags: javascript, date

I am working on Date functionality. I stuck at one point. I get date in YYYY-MM-DD format. So let say today is 2019-02-27 then I would like to get "Today" instead of date. Then yesterday was 2019-02-26 so I would like to get "Yesterday" and other date like 2019-02-25 would be displayed just as it is.

Note : I get date value as a string.

Any help would be great.

Thank You..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you want the strings "Today" and "Yesterday" then just compare the date to today's date and yesterday's date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js library

```js
let date= new Date();
let dateyday=new Date("2019-02-26");//pass date as a string

let c=moment(date).calendar(); 
console.log(c)
console.log(moment(dateyday).calendar())
console.log(c.split(" ")[0])//split to get today
console.log(moment(dateyday).calendar().split(" ")[0])//split to get yesterday
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For more you can refer here -https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score -1):

This will give you idea to start.

```
const isToday = (someDate) => {
            const today = new Date()
           return someDate.getDate() == today.getUTCDate() &&
            someDate.getMonth() == today.getUTCMonth() &&
            someDate.getFullYear() == today.getUTCFullYear()
        }; 
        isToday(new Date("2019-02-27")) // true
```

Comment: "2019-02-27" will be parsed as UTC, but you're comparing it to a local date so it will be wrong for the period of the host timezone offset around midnight (which can be up to 14 hours).

Comment: @RobG  yeah you are right. Anwers is edited accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a bit too precise for what you need, but using milliseconds etc.

```js
let date1 = new Date('2019-02-27');
let date2 = new Date('2019-02-26');
let date3 = new Date('2018-02-23');
let dateDynamic = new Date(Date.now() - 1000*60*60*12); // date with 12 hours subtrated


const response = (date) => { 

  const day = 1000*60*60*24;
  console.log(day);
  let dteToday = Date.now()-day;
  let dteYesterday = dteToday-day;
  let dteCompare = date.getTime();
  console.log(`${dteToday} - ${dteYesterday} : ${dteCompare}`);
  return (dteToday < dteCompare) ? 'today' : (dteYesterday < dteCompare) ? 'yesterday' : date.toString();
  
};



console.log(response(date1));
console.log(response(date2));
console.log(response(date3));
console.log(response(dateDynamic));
```

Comment: This fails for the same reason the others do: YYYY-MM-DD format dates are parsed as UTC, so for me it's 28 Feb but the above tells me 27 Feb is "today". Also, not all days are 8.64e7 ms long where daylight saving is observed.

Comment: @RobG I really hope you did not down vote me based on that. Adding an offset for time zone is not really difficult.

Comment: Also Date.now() is utc as well. So why would this not work?

Comment: I downvoted because it returns incorrect results as explained in my comment. If you want to know why it's wrong, ask a question. There isn't enough room in comments to provide a decent answer. There is no need to convert the string to a date, you just need to compare the current day, month and year with their respective timestamp components.